# Laravel spatie translatable and sluggable (translatable slugs)

Tags: php, laravel, slug

So I have just discovered the package [laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) and I am trying to setup [translatable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable) slugs. I got an error with the route model binding, error 404. So I created a simple migration, simple model and simple route, but the same error occurs. My database supports json.

My migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->json('name');
        $table->json('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;
use Spatie\Sluggable\HasTranslatableSlug;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations, HasTranslatableSlug;

    public $translatable = ['name', 'slug'];

    /**
     * Get the options for generating the slug.
     */
    public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
    {
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
    }

    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Artisan tinker shows me that the Post I created has been added and it looks like this:

```
+"name": "{"nl": "test"}",
+"slug": "{"nl": "test"}",
```

My locale is indeed `nl` at the moment but browsing to the following route gives me a 404 error:

```
use App\Models\Post;

Route::get('posts/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    dd($post);
});
```

My question is, what am I missing here? Regular slugs with this package are working like a charm. Also, the translatable package is working like a charm. It is just the translated slugs I am having an issue with right now.

Comment: Did you try inside your route changing posts/{post} to posts/{post.slug} ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have actually tried this yes, but I will check it again later and see if I can get it to work

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of laravel, installed only the packages I need and now it works. So I will have to do some troubleshooting to find the issue in my application. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a fresh Laravel 9 installation it worked like a charm and thus I have upgraded my Laravel 8 to Laravel 9 and it is working now.